# Streaming server side encrypted videos on S3 with cloudfront

Tags: amazon-s3, video-streaming, amazon-cloudfront

I am using amazon S3 storage along with Server-Side Encryption with Customer-Provided Keys (SSE-C) for storing video files. I am using Django as my backend server and have stored all the name keys and secret keys associated to each file in the database on an EC2 container.

I want to stream these videos using amazon cloudfront service. I have created and configured a cloudfront distribution with S3 storage. I am able to serve the non-encrypted videos very easily but i cannot access the encrypted videos as it requires the name key and secret key in order to access the server side encrypted data.

I couldn't find any help in this regard. Is it even possible to serve the server side encrypted (SSE-C) media files using cloudfront?

If possible, kindly guide me to the best solution.
Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it requires the name key and secret key in order to access the server side encrypted data.

That's not the entirety of problem; however.  [CloudFront signed URLs with an origin access identity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html) will transparently re-sign requests so that S3 will allow access to those objects when CloudFront concludes that the request is authorized, but you can't create a CloudFront signed URL that's compatible with SSE-C.

This, in turn, is because SSE-C in S3 does not support passing the necessary parameters to S3 in the query string.

> When using the presigned URL to upload a new object, retrieve an existing object, or retrieve only object metadata, you must provide all the encryption headers in your client application
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html

The encryption parameters must be sent as headers, not as query parameters, with SSE-C.

And, if you think about it, there seems to be little purpose to encrypting objects with keys that are revealed *and logged* with each request made -- the keys would be in the query string.

SSE-S3 works transparently with CloudFront.  SSE-KMS, I would expect to be supported as well (since, based on the S3 API documentation, there are no encryption-related headers required (or allowed) for `GET` requests).

> Encryption request headers, like x-amz-server-side-encryption, should not be sent for GET requests if your object uses server-side encryption with AWS KMS–managed encryption keys (SSE-KMS) or server-side encryption with Amazon S3–managed encryption keys (SSE-S3)
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html

Comment: Thanks Michael for your response. But it is still a bit unclear to me. It would be very kind of you to elaborate a bit further. This is what i understood from your answer (please correct me if i am wrong) : SSE-C type encryption is not suitable if one wants to stream content via cloudfront. In order to serve data through cloudfront and keep it encrypted on S3, one would have to use a type of server side encryption where keys are managed by amazon itself not the client like SSE-KMS .

Comment: or can i still be able to stream SSE-C encrypted videos by passing secret key and name key in request header?

Comment: I don't think CloudFront will pass the necessary headers to S3 even if your application can inject them into the request.  In fact, thinking about it, I'm not sure whether CloudFront will work with SSE-KMS, either, at least in some S3 regions.  Newer regions, like London, it might, but older regions, like Oregon, it almost certainly won't, because of some in-place design characteristics that would require changes that would break some existing uses.  Can you explain your motivation for controlling encryption this way?  Perhaps you are solving the wrong problem?